# Xcode compiler custom compiler vs apple llvm 8.0 and apple review

Tags: ios, objective-c, llvm

I need to obfuscate my iOS mostly `C` and `Objective-C` based app. 
https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator/

`llvm-obfuscator` provide quite well solution without much additional work related. Obviously it will not prevent people from reversing it but at least it will lift a bar a little. App it self is designed good enough to protect few security related mechanisms but I would like to compile it with custom compiler to make it even more harder. But it raises few questions

1. If apple actually allow compiling with custom compilers
2. How it may affect speed and stability of application, `o-llvm` is
   quite old 3.6.1 while apple already published their `llvm 8.0` - not
   sure what has been added improved or changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o-llvm does not support latest xcode. I have abandoned idea and wrote my own obfuscation script which encrypts all variables and methods except Cocoa ones. It's not that good like o-llvm but it works great.